# Disk Encryption Juno/Windows 10 - Dual Boot from separate hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hdd, full-disk-encryption

I have two separate drives with Window and EOS Juno.

I'd like to encrypt both systems but want to avoid any booting issues.

Any recommendation how this can be achieved?

```
Model: SAMSUNG MZVLB512HAJQ-000L7 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB  273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, hidden, esp
 2      274MB   290MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   511GB  511GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      511GB   512GB  1049MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag


Model: TOSHIBA-RC100 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  240GB  240GB  ext4
```

I am considering VeraCrypt. I haven't encrypted Elementary at installation.

Is it possible to encrypt/decrypt both hard drives using same encryption key/software? i.e. get Encryption password prompt before GRUB and access either system?

Thanks